# Microsoft Azure HIPAA Database Compliance

Tags: database, azure, sql-server-ce

I'm looking into developing Health Care related apps on Microsoft Azure; however, I've been told that SQL Server Azure is not HIPAA compliant.   Now, I heard that Azure Web Development and Virtual Machines are HIPAA Compliant.  Question, are local databases on Azure Virtual Machines HIPPA compliant (ie SQL Server Compact, MySQL, etc...)?  I know this is a vague question, but Azure seems like a great development platform to work with.  Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It's not that Virtual Machines are HIPAA-compliant; rather a BAA can be offered for apps using Virtual Machines. The app itself would still need to pass whatever compliance.

If you look at the [Azure Trust Center](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/compliance/), you'll see details of HIPAA BAA, along witha  link to Azure [HIPAA Implementation Guidance](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/8/8483B6A9-1865-4D17-B6F1-5B66D5C29B10/Windows%20Azure%20HIPAA%20Implementation%20Guidance.pdf).

I'm not a lawyer and cannot counsel you on the fine details of HIPAA and your app. However, I read through the compliance guide  <strike>and it only calls out Windows Azure SQL as not in scope</strike>. For Virtual Machines, the responsibility falls on you to deal with certain things. From the doc:

> Customers are responsible for their environment once the service has
>   been provisioned, including their applications, data content, virtual
>   machines, access credentials, and compliance with regulatory
>   requirements applicable to their particular industry and locale.

Comment: SQL Database is now covered under the HIPAA Business Associate Agreement.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/23/microsoft-extends-its-trailblazing-commitments-to-data-privacy.aspx